# Can't navigate Time Machine interface (going backwards/forwards in time) since upgrading to Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: mac, time-machine, backup, macos

Since upgrading to Mac OS X Yosemite, when I open Time Machine on a folder, I can't navigate backwards in time anymore, on any folder. The arrows are grayed out. Usually, this is because Time Machine needs a bit of time to load older backups, but I have given it a few minutes to load and it still does not work.

Strangely enough, the only time that there is no problem is when I restart my Mac. Once I restart, then I open a folder and open Time Machine, then I can navigate backwards in time, almost immediately, too. But after that, no folder that I open in Time Machine in the future will allow me to move back in time, until I restart once again, then I am able to only navigate a single folder.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Things I have already tried:

- Repair Disk Permissions on Macintosh HD
- Repair Disk on Time Machine drive.

Comment: check inside the time machine drive/backups.backupdb & make sure it don't consider it a new machine myMac & myMac(2)

Comment: I checked, and it looks fine. Just one Mac there. Plus, that shouldn't be the problem, since I can use Time Machine, but only in specific cases. And backups still work.

Comment: Same problem here. I can click the windows that are "behind" the frontmost window, and maybe 4 out of 5 clicks move me back in time more than one snapshot. But I'd like to access 6 month old backups, and this is clearly not the way...

Comment: @NikoNyman I can't even click the windows behind the frontmost window.  Anybody find a solution to this?

Answer (score 5):

Have you given [this](https://discussions.apple.com/message/28858835#28858835) a try?

> While in Time Machine, press the key combination shift-command-C. The
>   front window will show all mounted volumes. All snapshots should now
>   be accessible. Select the one you want and navigate to the files you
>   want to restore.

Comment: This seems to work for me. Weird default behavior to hide everything.